# calculation of $\mathrm{div} [r \times a]$

Tags: vector-analysis

so I have to calculate (straight, showing all the steps):

$$\mathrm{div} [r \times a]$$ where $a$ is a conts and $r$ is a motion vector, so first:

$$[r \times a] = \begin{vmatrix} \vec{i} & \vec{j} & \vec{k} \\
x & y & z \\
a_x & a_y & a_z \end{vmatrix} =  \vec{i}ya_z +\vec{k}xa_y+\vec{j}za_x-\vec{k}ya_x -\vec{i}za_y-\vec{j}zx_a$$

known that:

$$\mathrm{div} = \frac{\partial}{\partial{x}} + \frac{\partial}{\partial{y}} + \frac{\partial}{\partial{z}}$$

what should I substitute to div defenition above from the determinant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid the divergence operator isn't quite what you said! The divergence operator takes as input a *vector* field, and returns a scalar field. By definition,
$$ {\rm div}(F_1 \vec i + F_2 \vec j + F_3 \vec k) = \frac{\partial F_1}{\partial x} +\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial F_3}{\partial z}.  $$

In your example,
$$ F_1 = ya_z - za_y, \ \ \ \ F_2 = za_x - xa_z, \ \ \ \ F_3 = xa_y - ya_x,$$
so you just need to substitute this into my formula.